# Select specific column value from multiple relational table using where condition in Laravel ORM

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I have two tables named `contacts` and `clients`. Both tables have `group_id` as foreign_key. Now, I want to get `phone`column value from both tables when user `$request->groupid` will found a group from `groups`table. I am trying something like this. But getting empty array. Would someone help me please!

```
$getPhoneNumbers = Group::with(['hasContacts' => function($query){
                             $query->select('phone')->where('is_active', 1);
                        }])->with(['clients' => function($q){
                             $q->select('phone')->where('status', 1);
                        }])->where('id', $request->groupid)->get();
```

In **Group** model -

```
public function clients()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Client', 'group_id', 'id');
}

public function hasContacts()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Contact', 'group_id', 'id');
}
```

Comment: You should rename the relationship method `hasContacts()` to `contacts()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need to select the foreign key `group_id` that Laravel requires to match the eager loading results to their parents:

```php
$getPhoneNumbers = Group::with(['hasContacts' => function($query){
                             $query->select('group_id', 'phone')->where('is_active', 1);
                        }])->with(['clients' => function($q){
                             $q->select('group_id', 'phone')->where('status', 1);
                        }])->where('id', $request->groupid)->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the relationship methods you should first get the group object and then call them. Also, please rename `hasContacts()` to `contacts()` to follow conventions.

```
$group = Group::find($request->groupid);

if (!$group) {
    # group not found
}

$clientPhoneNumbers = $group->clients()->where('status', 1)->pluck('phone')
$contactPhoneNumbers = $group->contacts()->where('is_active', 1)->pluck('phone')
```

This uses pluck to get a single column as a eloquent `Collection`. You can use `$clientPhoneNumbers->toArray()` to get the phone numbers as an array (and likewise for the other `Collection`).

Group model:

```
public function clients()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Client', 'group_id', 'id');
}

public function contacts()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Contact', 'group_id', 'id');
}
```